# Why isn't my binary search giving me a result for the first element?

Tags: c++, binary-search

I'm trying to return the index of the element to be searched. All the elements are being detected except the first element. What's wrong? Why is the function not returning index 0?

```
using namespace std;
int binsearch(int a[],int x,int y)
{
    int low=a[0];
    int high=a[x-1];
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(y==a[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if(y>a[mid])
        {
            low=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            high=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int x=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int y;
    cin>>y;
    cout<<binsearch(a,x,y);
}
```

Comment: `low` and `high` are indices right? Why are they being initialized with values from the array instead of 0 and `x -1`? Consider using meaningful parameter names. Nobody is going to assume `x` is size and `y` is the value you're looking for so it just makes the code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int low=a[0];
int high=a[x-1];
```

should be

```
int low=0;
int high=x-1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man . that was a silly mistake :0